# What is the difference between sdl2 and sdl2_sys?

Tags: rust, sdl-2, rust-cargo

As far as I can tell, [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys) is a crate of automatically generated bindings for all of SDL2, and [sdl2](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2) is a crate of bindings based on [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys), which lacks equivalents to certain functions, specifically `IMG_LoadSVG_RW`.

I have seen a few sources say that [sdl2](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2) is a safe wrapper for SDL2 ([here](https://nercury.github.io/rust/opengl/tutorial/2018/02/08/opengl-in-rust-from-scratch-01-window.html)), but I haven't seen anyone say the same for [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys).
I have to write `unsafe` a lot when using functions from [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys), which I don't like because it means there is no longer a guarantee that what I write will be safe.
Another issue with [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys) is that functions sometimes return c types (so far I've only had to deal with *c_char but I'm sure there are more), which are awkward to convert back.
Finally, every tutorial I have found so far is for [sdl2](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2), so It is always harder to find out how exactly to do something.

I need to use `IMG_LoadSVG_RW`, so it's clear that I will have to use [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys) in some way, but I would like to know wether it is better to only use [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys) where I can't use [sdl2](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2) and deal with the problems that causes, or to use [sdl2_sys](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2_sys) for everything and have a significantly worse experience.

Comment: Why not open a pull request to `std2` with wrapper around `IMG_LoadSVG_RW`? It is easy to do and would help other people too.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros I've never tried open source before but this could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `*_sys` crate contains (often automatically generated) one-to-one bindings to the C API of the library in question, some Rust settings to link to the library, and nothing else. The main, non-`sys` crates offer a memory-safe and ergonomic interface to the library, written using the bindings from the `sys` crate.

Using `sys` crates directly is usually not recommended - you may as well just be writing C. However the safe bindings in the non-`sys` crate are written by third parties who may not have gotten around to safely binding every single bit of functionality in the library, so they may be lacking.

Comment: Presumably the non-sys crate bindings are no safer than the sys ones when used correctly?

Comment: @Jacob I think you have it the other way around. The non-sys crates usually expose bindings that ensure memory safety - for example, using lifetimes, proper mutable-immutable rules, and drop. The raw C bindings can (and should) be used safely, but the compiler can't check for you.